# How to remove table and cells borders when they are clicked

Tags: css, angularjs

I created a table like this:

```
 <table class="table table-without-margin">
                <thead>
                ...
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 <tr ng-show="row.sprint == undefined "
                    ng-repeat="row in rowCollectionUserStories | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse |filter:search"
                    ng-class="row.selectedCell ? 'cellSelectedClass' : ''">

                  <td data-ng-click="viewDetailsUserstory(row)" class="table-cell05">{{row.voters.length}}</td>
                  <td data-ng-click="viewDetailsUserstory(row)" class="table-cell23">#{{row.num}} {{row.subject}}</td>

 </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

And in the css:

```
.panel-body-backlog-userstories-list .table {
  border-bottom:0px !important;
}
.panel-body-backlog-userstories-list .table th, .table td {
  border: 1px !important;
}
.panel-body-backlog-userstories-list .fixed-table-container {
  border:0px !important;
}

.panel-body-backlog-userstories-list table tr:hover,
.panel-body-backlog-userstories-list table tr:focus,
.panel-body-backlog-userstories-list table tr:active
{

  background:rgba(229, 249, 255, 0.45);
  border:none;

}
```

It works, but when I select column and row, it shows me its edges.
How could I delete them?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `border: 0 none transparent; outline: 0 none transparent; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;`

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks you very much :D

Comment: Right on, no problem :)